# jquery removing items from the array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to find answer that I changed a bit and tried to make it work but without success.

I would like to remove item when user press x button:

Part of JS code:

```
    animals = temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        newOutput += '<p>' + animals[i] 
                   + '<input type="number" class="animals-input pull-right text-right" value="0" />' 
                   + '<a href="#" onClick="deleteItem(' + animals[i] 
                   + ')" class="pull-right delete-item">x</a></p>';
    };
    $('.animals-input').innerHTML = newOutput;
```

[full js fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/yq38sLLz/)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `$('.animals-input').innerHTML = newOutput;` should be `$('.animals-input').html(newOutput);`

Comment: It doesn't work like that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {

    newOutput.push('<p>' + animals[i] + '<input type="number" class="animals-input pull-right text-right" value="0" />' + '<a href="#" onClick="deleteItem(\'' + i + '\')" class="pull-right delete-item">x</a></p>');
  };
  $('#list').html(newOutput.join(""));
```

[**Updated Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yq38sLLz/1/)

You need to change from this

```
onClick="deleteItem(' + animals[i] + ')"
```

to

```
onClick="deleteItem(\'' + i + '\')"
```

as in `deleteItem()` function you are passing the array index not the array value. Also, you need to put quotes while passing the parameter to the function, otherwise you get errors.

Comment: in updated fiddle, total count doesn't work, not sure why